# Heroku via Github, where is my JSON files updated?

Tags: json, github, heroku

This isn't exactly a question in need of help, however, I am curious as to which file is updated, when updated, when I use Heroku via Github. Would it be the one within my Github or does Heroku save those files and update them somewhere else?

All I'm trying to accomplish is edit a JSON file so I can store an integer to each player (I'm using a worker, for a discord bot). Also, yes, that seems like what I am trying to do. Anything that saves the information, doesn't require money and isn't too complex

EDIT:

This issue has been solved with the answer that Heroku simply cannot update JSON files. I have resolved it myself by moving my host onto a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B+. Thank you for all the answers.

Comment: Are you talking about modifying a file on the Heroku side? E.g., you want to persist some data to disk?

Comment: All I'm trying to accomplish is edit a JSON file so I can store an integer to each player (I'm using a worker, for a discord bot). Also, yes, that seems like what I am trying to do. Anything that saves the information, doesn't require money and isn't too complex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> All I'm trying to accomplish is edit a JSON file so I can store an integer to each player (I'm using a worker, for a discord bot). Also, yes, that seems like what I am trying to do. Anything that saves the information, doesn't require money and isn't too complex

Heroku's [filesystem is ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem). Any changes you save to the local filesystem will be lost when your dyno restarts, which [happens frequently](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#restarting). If you scale your application to multiple dynos you'll also run into trouble since the ephemeral filesystems are dyno-local.

Your best bet is to use a proper client-server datastore, like PostgreSQL. Heroku provides [its own Postgres service](https://www.heroku.com/postgres), which has a free tier. If Postgres isn't to your liking, feel free to choose [something else](https://elements.heroku.com/addons).

Answer (score 1):

When you use Heroku's GitHub Sync feature, a deployment will retrieve your code directly from GitHub.
Those files aren't saved anywhere else. A new deployment from master will take the code fresh from GitHub.

Comment: But does it actually update the JSON files? Because whenever it should do so, it doesn't seem to show

Comment: You mean if you update files within your app, are they updated on GitHub? That's a No.

Comment: So essentially, you can't use JSON files with Heroku. That's kind of pointless unless there is an alternative for me to save information.

Comment: You can't save files to disk and expect them to be around on GitHub (or even after the app is restarted, as each running instance is an individual container) indeed.
Storing data can be achieved using a database, or a service such as S3.

Comment: Ok, but what if I didn't want to invest any money into storage? Also, how would I link it through GitHub?